# Can I have a python program close wihtout giving me a popup?

Tags: python

At the end of one of my programs, I put the following code:

```
print('Thank you for using this program!')
print('Goodbye')
time.sleep(10)
exit()
```

I did this to give the user some time to read the text, and then have the window close.  However, this has been giving me the following popup:
[image].

Is there any way I can have the window close without giving me this popup?

Comment: You can try `sys.exit` but i think its because you are using IDLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ‘import sys’ then exit using ‘sys.exit()’

Comment: This probably should have been a comment, instead of an answer.